# ENDISI calculate

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, algorithm

I'm new to ArcGIS. Can someone tell me why my ENDISI always equal to 1?

My algorithms:

("band02.tif" - 16170.19 * (("band06.tif" / "band07.tif") + "mndwi.tif" ^ 2)) / ("band02.tif" + 16170.19 * (("band06.tif" / "band07.tif") + "mndwi.tif" ^ 2))

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the `^` a "toThePowerOf" operator or a Bitwise Or?

Comment: It's "toThePowerOf" operator